# Return Time from the Modal Dialog when the Dialog is closed

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, jquery-events

I am opening a Child Modal Dialog window from my parent web page. The JavaScript code for opening the Dialog is as follows:-

```
function openmodalWin() {
        window.showModalDialog("ClockPopUP.aspx", "Clock", "dialogWidth:550px;dialogHeight:350px,");
        }
```

**The Asp Code is as Follows:-**

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Lunch" CausesValidation="false" CssClass="bigbuttons" style="background:url(../App_Themes/Images/green-box.gif)" Font-Bold="True"  ForeColor="White" Font-Size="Large" OnClientClick="openmodalWin(); return false;"
```

In my "ClockPopUp.aspx" I had used only one jQuery stop watch plugin which is just for showing purpose and no use except it. My requirement is that I want that as the user will close the ModalDialog, on the parent page we can capture the time when the Pop up will be closed, or the `ShowmodalDialog` will return datetime at `window.close()`.

Please try to solve this issue as I'm not so good in JavaScript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery UI has this functionality without the need to access another aspx page.

However, window.showModalDialog returns a value, so you'd need to alter your aspx to return something meaningful i.e.

window.returnValue = "whatever";
   window.close();

Then you can call it using

```
var returnValue = window.showModalDialog(...)
```

Comment: var dt=new Date(); 
window.returnValue="dt";Window.Close();

Are you telling like this in the child page?
If yes then will it return the exact closing time of Close event ?

Comment: Something like that, but don't put quotes around dt otherwise it'll return as a literal string.